# Decomposition of function in piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
a continuous a nonnegative function with compact support and let ε be a positive number. For
each positive integer $n$ define a function $f_n(x) : X → R$ by
$$
f_n(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad if\quad f(x) \leq  (n-1)\epsilon\\
            f(x)-(n-1)\epsilon & \quad if\quad (n-1)\epsilon<f(x) \leq n\epsilon\\
\epsilon & \quad if\quad f(x) >  n\epsilon\\
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

How to proof that $f(x)=\sum f_n(x)$ ?

Comment: how can $(n-1) \epsilon < 2 \epsilon$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: my mistake . i will correct it

Comment: You should say in wich set you apply the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\notin \text{supp}f$, the result is clear. Otherwise, let $N\ge 1$ be the unique integer such that $(N-1)\epsilon<f(x) \leq N\epsilon$. Then, $f_n(x)=0$ for $n\ge N+1$. Therefore,

$\sum f_n(x)=\sum^{N-1}_{n=1}\epsilon+(f(x)-(N-1)\epsilon)=(N-1)\epsilon+f(x)-(N-1)\epsilon=f(x).$